# Excel VSTO C# - how to read previous cell value in Excel VSTO

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I'm trying to create an add-in for Excel using Excel VSTO C# whereby a cell would have autocomplete option based on value in the previous cell.

for example, if cell A1 contains value fruits, then A2 will have autocomplete list like banana, apple, mango, etc

is it possible in Excel VSTO C #?

Comment: please review [Should I use tags in titles?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging), please include the code you have so far and where you are having issues (follow [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) guidelines in that respect).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do that, but its a lot of work to implement it. 
Try ExcelDNA that might have the feature you want included, but i'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see a proposal for your question.
In the window code for the object Sheet1 (Sheet1.cs) add the following code:

```
void ThisWorkbook_SheetChange(object Sh, Excel.Range Target)
    {
        Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)Sh;
        Range RS = Globals.ThisWorkbook.ThisApplication.ActiveCell;
        string[] SelectedCell = Target.Address.ToString().Split('$');
        string PreviousCell = SelectedCell[0] + SelectedCell[1] +Convert.ToString((Convert.ToInt32(SelectedCell[2])));
        Range cell = sheet.Range[PreviousCell];
        if (cell.Text=="fruits")
        {
            RS.Validation.Delete();
            RS.Validation.Add(
                Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateList,
                Excel.XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertInformation,
                Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween,
                GlobalVars.flatList
                );
            RS.Validation.IgnoreBlank = true;
            RS.Validation.InCellDropdown = true;
        }
    }
```

In the subroutine  private void InternalStartup() add the following line:

```
this.Application.ActiveWorkbook.SheetChange += new Excel.WorkbookEvents_SheetChangeEventHandler(ThisWorkbook_SheetChange);
```

In the window code for ThisWorkBook (ThisWorkBook.cs), add the following code in the subroutine private void ThisWorkbook_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e). It should like:

```
private void ThisWorkbook_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Sheet1 wsMain = Globals.Sheet1;
        GlobalVars.list.Add("Mango");
        GlobalVars.list.Add("Bananas");
        GlobalVars.list.Add("Grapes");
        GlobalVars.flatList = string.Join(",", GlobalVars.list.ToArray());
    }
```

When you type the word "fruits" in any cell and press enter, the cell below will show a list with the options as shown in the next figure:

[image]

I expect this can be useful.